# Intervention\Image\Exception\NotWritableException: Can&#039;t write image data to path Image\Image.php on line 143

Tags: laravel, intervention

I am using Image intervention to save base64 image in Laravel. It is working fine on cpanel. But when I changed server, it gives the above mentioned error.

I have checked the permissions and image folder presence. I don't know what else to do. Please help.

```
           $file = $request->profile_pic;
           $fileNewName = substr(md5(rand()),0, 100).'.' . explode('/', 
           explode(':', substr($file, 0, strpos($file, ';')))[0])[0]; 
           $path = public_path('appImages/').$fileNewName;

       \Image::make($file)->save($path);
```

Comment: appImages is not writable or www-data doesn't have access.

Comment: check the path on error log, and the correct public_path , path in your server

Comment: How can I verify the issues you mentioned? I am using windows OS on aws

Comment: @flakerimi how can I give access to www-data. I am new to aws kindly help. I am using windows OS on aws

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/file-permissions-on-windows

Comment: I have found the issue if it helps anyone. I was not saving the file extension with its name. Now I am and it's working. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @RizwanAshraf thankyou, this is the exception reason for me in windows os